# Convert Pandas dataframe with multiindex to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like

```
     df = 
    Index1 Index2 Index3   column1  column2
     i11    i12    i13      2          5
     i11    i12    i23      3          8
     i21    i22    i23      4          5
```

How to convert this into list of dictionaries with keys as `Index3, column1, column2` and values as in the respective cells.

So, expected output:

```
     [[{Index3: i13, column1: 2, column2: 5}, {Index3: i23, column1: 3, column2: 8}], [{Index3: i23, column1: 4, column2: 5}]]
```

Please note that the same values of `Index1` and `Index2` form 1 inner list and the values won't be repeated.

Comment: Are you sure about repeating key in dict -> "Index3"?
Please provide some code to copy/paste with dataframe.

Comment: yes, the key is repeating in Index3.

Comment: This was formed by grouping by on Index1, Index2, and Index3, and summing the remaining columns `df = original_df.groupby(['Index1' 'Index2', 'Index3']).sum()`, which were initially columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'Index1': ["i11", "i12", "i13"],  
     'Index2': ["i21", "i22", "i23"],      
     'Index3': ["i31", "i32", "i33"],      
     'column1': [2, 3,4],
     'column2': [5, 8, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This should fit:

```
a = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    a.append({"Index3": df.iloc[2,i],"column 1": df.iloc[i,3], "column2": df.iloc[i,4]})
```

Res:

```
[{'Index3': 'i13', 'column 1': 2, 'column2': 5},
 {'Index3': 'i23', 'column 1': 3, 'column2': 8},
 {'Index3': 'i33', 'column 1': 4, 'column2': 5}]
```

Comment: Hi @sejuh_M, thanks for this answer. I want list of lists, where inner list consists of same values on Index1 and Index2. Please note the closing brackets after `{'Index3': 'i23', 'column 1': 3, 'column2': 8}` in my example.